Fetch posgresql data in JSON format including both filtered and non-filtered data
I'm working in a multi-tenant software to manage inventory of products and I'm having difficulties to create a query to bring products inventory based on quantity criteria.
Use case: Bring all products with all their inventory from all warehouses from current user's organization where product type is from appliances and their quantity in warehouse x is 0 and in warehouse y >0
Expected Result for organization abc, product type as appliances and warehouse warh65=0 and warehouse warh777>0,  would be an array of products with an inventory property listing all warehouses inventory for the product not only the one being queried, for example:
[
 {
   product_id: producta,
   ...product,
   inventory:[
     {warehouse_id:warh65, warehouse_quantity: 0},
     {warehouse_id:warh098, warehouse_quantity: 5},
     {warehouse_id:warh777, warehouse_quantity: 2},
   ]
 },
]

Here is the point I am at the moment, where it brings an array with producta and productc, but it doesn't list the rest of inventory in other warehouses, only the one being queried. If I add a second condition for another warehouse the returned array is empty.
Using Postgresql
SELECT p.*, JSON_AGG(row(i.inven_warehouse_id, i.inventory_quantity)) as inventory
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN inventory AS i
ON p.product_id = i.inven_product_id
WHERE p.product_org = orgabc AND p.product_type='appliances' AND (i.inven_warehouse_id='warn65' AND i.inventory_quantity=0)
GROUP BY p.product_id

Here is a visual aid for the tables and relations. Thank you in advance for the assistance.



product_id
product_org
product_type
product_...




producta
orgabc
appliances
row


productb
orgabc
hand tools
row


productc
orgabc
hand tools
row






org_id
org_...




orgabc
row


orgxyz
row






warehouse_id
warehouse_org
warehouse_name




warh65
orgabc
this


warh098
orgabc
that


warh777
orgabc
that


warh523
orgxyz
that


warhhgy
orgxyz
that






inven_warehouse_id
inven_product_id
inventory_quantity




warh65
producta
0


warh098
producta
5


warh777
producta
2


warh65
productb
3


warh098
productb
1


warh777
productb
0


warh65
productc
0


warh098
productc
1


warh777
productc
1




can you add the expected output?

inventory_quantity==0  hope,it is a typo

inventory_quantity==0 was a typo. Fixed.
@samhita it is already in the text.

for producta, warh777 do you mean the quantity should be 2 instead of 1? my answer shows 2 tho

Please either ask about bad code with the obligatory [mre] & why you
think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it
doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative
documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you
can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because
misconceptions will get in the way of understanding the latter. [ask] [Help]

Based on the condition given,

Expected Result for organization abc, product type as appliances and
warehouse warh65=0 and warehouse warh777>0


First fetch all data you need by INNER JOIN
Then use EXISTS to check whether the required conditions are met in the fetch query(warehouse warh65=0 and warehouse warh777>0)

I have built this query, let me know if my understanding is correct.
Fiddle seems to be down at the moment, so I could not share the live link with you.
WITH filtered_products AS (
  SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    p.product_org,
    p.product_type,
    JSON_AGG(
      DISTINCT 
      JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'warehouse_id', i.inven_warehouse_id, 
        'warehouse_quantity', i.inventory_quantity
      )
    ) AS inventory
  FROM 
    products AS p
  INNER JOIN 
    inventory AS i ON p.product_id = i.inven_product_id
  INNER JOIN
    warehouse AS w ON i.inven_warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id
  WHERE 
    p.product_org = 'orgabc' 
    AND p.product_type = 'appliances'
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM inventory 
      WHERE inven_product_id = p.product_id 
      AND inven_warehouse_id = 'warh65' 
      AND inventory_quantity = 0
    )
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM inventory 
      WHERE inven_product_id = p.product_id 
      AND inven_warehouse_id = 'warh777' 
      AND inventory_quantity > 0
    )
  GROUP BY 
    p.product_id, p.product_org, p.product_type
)
SELECT 
  'orgabc' AS organization,
  JSON_AGG(
    JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
      'product_id', fp.product_id,
      'product_org', fp.product_org,
      'product_type', fp.product_type,
      'inventory', fp.inventory
    )
  ) AS products
FROM 
  filtered_products fp;

Output JSON
[
  {
    "inventory": [
      {
        "warehouse_id": "warh098",
        "warehouse_quantity": 5
      },
      {
        "warehouse_id": "warh65",
        "warehouse_quantity": 0
      },
      {
        "warehouse_id": "warh777",
        "warehouse_quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "producta",
    "product_org": "orgabc",
    "product_type": "appliances"
  },
  {
    "inventory": [
      {
        "warehouse_id": "warh098",
        "warehouse_quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "warehouse_id": "warh65",
        "warehouse_quantity": 0
      },
      {
        "warehouse_id": "warh777",
        "warehouse_quantity": 1
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "productc",
    "product_org": "orgabc",
    "product_type": "appliances"
  }
]


I just implemented here in my code and it is working like a charm. I cannot express in words how fantastic this is, @samhita. I would never come up with such query by myself. Thanks a ton!
I will take a moment to understand how it works to improve my knowledge base. Thank you!

Thank you for letting me know :) Super glad that it worked for you :)

The other answer is completely over-complicated. You just need conditional aggregation in a HAVING to filter the grouped results by the whole group.
SELECT
  p.*,
  jsonb_agg(
    jsonb_build_object(
      'warehouse_id', i.inven_warehouse_id,
      'quantity', i.inventory_quantity
    )
  ) as inventory
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON p.product_id = i.inven_product_id
WHERE p.product_org = 'orgabc'
  AND p.product_type = 'appliances'
GROUP BY p.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE i.inven_warehouse_id = 'warh65'  AND i.inventory_quantity = 0) > 0
  AND  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE i.inven_warehouse_id = 'warh777' AND i.inventory_quantity > 0) > 0;

If you want the final result as one big JSON then you need two levels of aggregation.
db<>fiddle
